# How can I create my own QR codes for free?

Tags: url, hyperlink, qr-code, graphics-editing, generator

I'm planning to implement a QR code on a poster that I'm designing, and it seems the most common way to do this is to use one of the [many](https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/) online [generators](https://www.qrcode-zebra.com/) out [there](https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/), but they either don't allow me to customise the QR code enough or they do but require subscription to their service for it.

That's ideal for a graphic designer or marketing exec with not much technical knowhow, but as someone with a little programmatic experience I figure that there must be a way to generate a fully-featured QR code on my own without needing to pay anything. For example, my QR code needs to have a transparent background in order to go on a dark flyer, a feature that none of the online generators are good at doing even if some purport to support it.

Is it possible to generate my own QR codes?

Comment: How customized do you want?
Also - If you have any reasonable image editor (I use paint.net) you can remove the background, or set it to black.

Comment: I was mainly thinking of the transparent background, as I was wary of doing that manually within Illustrator or Photoshop, but it looks like I'll have no other choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`libqrencode`](https://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/) is a library and `qrencode` is a command line utility for encoding data in a QR Code symbol.

I installed `qrencode` in my Kubuntu (from `qrencode` package) and successfully created a QR code as a PNG image.

Transparent background is [not a job for encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well). Use `qrencode`/`libqrencode` to get a basic image; then use an image manipulation tool (e.g `convert` from ImageMagick) to adjust it to your needs. Example:

```
qrencode -o - 'https://superuser.com/a/1523436/432690' | convert - -transparent white foo.png
```

<sup>Note: I'm not sure I got your idea of transparent background right.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

For windows/mac/linux, Inkscape has an extension by default. Look in Extensions/Render/Barcode/QR code.

The extension has a reference to the [originator's web page](https://www.qrcode.com/en/), but I didn't dig deep to find an reference to Inkscape's extension on the site.

I did confirm that I can enter any text into the extension input dialog box to get a working QR code. My QR code reader (iOS) displayed the random text or asked me to visit any URL I entered.

The extension provides for block size giving you the ability to adjust size as desired. As a vector file, the background is transparent by default.

[image: https://superuser.com/questions/1523429/how-can-i-create-my-own-qr-codes-for-free]

The above QR is this post's URL.

It appears that there may be some massaging necessary if this is to be used on a vinyl cutter or laser cutter, as boundaries are visible between the individual black blocks making up the overall shape.